# How to automatically name columns in R?

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have a dataset that currently looks like this:

```
   ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
1      100     100     100
2      100     100     100
3      100     100     100
4      200     200     200
5      300     300     300
6      400     400     400
7      400     400     400
8      500     500     500
9      500     500     500
10     600     600     600
11     700     700     700
```

In the real dataset, there are 100 columns. I would like to rename them X1,X2,X3,X4,X5....X100. For example:

```
    X1  X2  X3
1  100 100 100
2  100 100 100
3  100 100 100
4  200 200 200
5  300 300 300
6  400 400 400
7  400 400 400
8  500 500 500
9  500 500 500
10 600 600 600
11 700 700 700
```

Is there a way to do this without having to manually change each of the 100 column names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can assign the `names` with `paste`

```
names(df1) <- paste0("X", seq_along(df1))
```